# OptaPlanner - Create a good, initial solution by hand

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming

Is there a way to create an initial solution for OptaPlanner by hand, in Java code?

I know that I can write the `constructionHeuristic` in the config XML to create a good initial solution.

But if I can write a better initial solution than OptaPlanner founds, is there a way to start the planning from my solution?

Thanks,
Vilmos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of giving OptaPlanner a custom solution:

- You can generate any Solution you like ahead of time. If the `solution` you give to `solver.solve(solution)` is already initialized at the time, you do not need to call construction heuristics at all.
- If you instead wish to take an uninitialized solution and initialize it yourself in OptaPlanner, look into `CustomPhaseCommand`. Several OptaPlanner examples use that technique, see [Machine Reassignment](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/machinereassignment/solver/solution/initializer/ToOriginalMachineSolutionInitializer.java) as an example. (However, beware that this is not a public API and we therefore do not guarantee its long-term stability.)

Comment: if I initialize the solution beforehand, will OptaPlanner try to improve that? I'm trying to do a bit more complex VRP, and I can create a good, initial solution by hand - but if I call `solverManager.solveAndListen(id, problems::get, solution -> callback(solution))` then OptaPlanner is not improving on it in 20 minutes, which seems to be a bit strange.

Comment: Okay, I've created a very minimal problem for my VRP, and I'm pretty sure that if I'm going with the first method, OptaPlanner will not optimaze anything on it :'(

Comment: From the point of view of OptaPlanner, there is nothing special about a solution created this way, no reason why it should not work where other solutions would. I suggest you check the log and see what OptaPlanner does - preferrably enabling DEBUG logging, as that will give you more information on the work that is going on.

Comment: If a solution is generated ahead of time by chosing initial values for genuine planning variables, the dependent shadow variable are not automatically updated. Is it possible to have optaplanner trigger all variable listeners, in order to also correctly initialize the shadow variables?

Comment: Yes, there is a ScoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners() method for that purpose.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický, For the approach 1 (initialized solution, but no shadow vars), where should be `ScoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners()` called from? Is it possible to get it's instance somewhere before submitting the job? After submit the solving fails, due to null shadow vars.